# How do I set a specify RPS in locust ? like 500 requests per seconds

Tags: python, load-testing, locust

I am new for locust. I have a CSV file which records the requests rate. And I want to sent a specify number of requests to a website according to the CSV file, like 500 requests per seconds, how can I do this?

Please help me about this problem, Thanks

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sounds like what would be best for you is a Custom Load Shape. You can specify in code how many users get spawned at any given time during your test. You could read the values from your CSV and then set the user count and spawn rate appropriately.

http://docs.locust.io/en/stable/custom-load-shape.html

**EDIT:**

A Custom Load Shape lets you control the spawned number of users in code, but if you want to ensure you're getting a certain amount of Requests Per Second (RPS), that's going to be up to how you write your code. The code your Locust users runs needs to be written in such a way that each user is only making one request. Then in your Locust User class, you set `wait_time = constant(1)` or `wait_time = constant_pacing(1)`, whichever behavior you want.

http://docs.locust.io/en/stable/api.html?highlight=wait_time#locust.wait_time.constant

You can see this sort of pattern in all of the [code examples](https://github.com/locustio/locust/tree/master/examples/custom_shape) for custom shapes.

Comment: Thank you. I had tried this method, and I found the number of users is not equal to the number of requests.

Comment: Edited my answer to address your RPS concern.

Comment: It is also important to have the user randomly wait at least for the time between requests when starting, otherwise all users created at the same tick dogpile the API when starting up, only to then wait another second (if using `constant_pacing(1)`) for the next request. See https://github.com/locustio/locust/blob/master/examples/custom_shape/wait_user_count.py#L25 in the link already included in the answer